# Строчная или прописная?

Tags: орфография

ВТБ-Капитал, Альфа-Банк.

Answer (score 1):

Пишется так, как прописано в уставных документах.
Если бы это было не название, то причин для прописной во второй части дефисного слова не было бы. Но приходится считаться с фактическим положением вещей.

Влияние английского, безусловно, присутствует. Сама конструкция подобного рода (не банк ВБТ, а именно ВБТ-Банк, даже невзирая на тавтологию) явный англицизм.
Но если говорить о заглавной  букве, грамматика здесь ни при чем. Добро бы ещё "орфография". ;)

Answer (score 0):

"Альфа Банк" или Альфа-Банк пишется с большой буквы. Это слияние английской грамматики на русский язык - в английском языке все слова сложных имен собственных пишутся с прописной буквы.
"ВТБ-Капитал" подчиняется тем же правилам.

Comment: ВТБ-Капитал. Пишется ли второе слово с прописной буквы?

Comment: Почему русская орфография должна подчиняться правилам английской грамматики? И где можно найти правило русской орфографии, на которое Вы ссылаетесь?